# How to write recursive ucwords method

Tags: php, string

I need all words to be in proper case, with first letters capitalized and others lower case.

I tried:

```
array_walk_recursive($my_array,'ucwords');
```

But I guess the function needs to be user-defined.

So I wrote:

```
function ucrecursive($value,$key) {
    return ucwords($value);
}

array_walk_recursive(&$my_array,'ucrecursive');
```

Still doesn't work. Any ideas?

EDIT:  sample data:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [count] => 768
            [value] => SATIN NICKEL
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [count] => 525
            [value] => POLISHED CHROME
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [count] => 180
            [value] => AGED BRONZE
        )
```

etc...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Should be pretty easy to build it yourself:

```
function ucWordsRecursive( array &$array ) {
    foreach( $array as &$value ) {
        if( is_array( $value ) ) {
             ucWordsRecursive( $value );
        }
        else if( is_string( $value ) ){
            $value = ucwords( strtolower( $value ) );
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't appear to be working. I copied it word for word.

Comment: I have tried it, and I tried the next answer as well and it also worked fine. What type of sample data do you have, and what version of Php are you using? (`phpinfo()`)

Comment: php 5.3.2.1. I'll put the sample data in my question right now.

Comment: I guess that you wanted the strings lowercased first then. Updated answer.

Comment: Oh my god almighty. I thought ucwords did that. I hate my life. Thank you so much, everything works now. Now I'm getting my expected behavior.

Answer (score 3):

```
array_walk_recursive($my_array,function(&$value) {
    $value = ucwords($value);
});
```

Try this

Comment: Looks wonderful, but doesn't work for some reason. The manual says that the `array_walk_recursive()` callback function usually takes two arguments, $value and $key. I'll see if I can tweak it to work.

Comment: This method is more concise but doesn't make the words into proper case. I have all-caps words that need to be lowercased first.

Answer (score 1):

that would be :

```
array_walk_recursive($my_array,function(&$value) {
    $value = ucwords(strtolower($value));
});
```

Comment: Nice, but maybe this should be an edit of Madara Uchiha's answer?

Comment: that could yes, i have never edited someone else answer; i find it slightly intrusive

Answer (score 0):

If anyone wants to build it with recursive without any build-in functions

```
function capitalizeWords ($array) {
 if (count($array) === 1) {
     return [ucwords($array[0])];
 }
 $res = capitalizeWords(array_slice($array,0,-1));
 array_push($res,ucwords(array_slice($array,count($array)-1)[0]));
 return $res;

}

capitalizeWords(['php','javascript','golang']);`
```